# ASIC verification of a multiport switch

Tags: system-verilog

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyVxOX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a DUT that can take packets from all 4 identical interfaces (A, B, C, D) Packets from one port can go to either one of the output ports (1,2,3,4). Example: Packets from A can go onto 1, 2, 3 or 4. Packets from port B can go to 1, 2, 3 or 4 and so on. Packets coming on the same port are in order but packets can be serviced in any order between A, B, C, D (no order is maintained since all 4 interfaces can be active at the same time sending packets).

How do I verify such a DUT? What scoreboard data structure to use?

Answer (score 1):

I think I would approach this by maintaining 16 separate queues (FIFO buffers), one for each of the possible paths through the DUT, since from your description, that is the only sense in which order is preserved. When a packet is transmitted into one of the input ports, it is also placed in the appropriate queue.

When a packet comes out of an output port, check each of the four queues associated with that port and make sure that it is the first packet in one of them. If so, remove it from the queue and keep going.

If not, the level of diagnostics to include in the testbench is up to you. For example, you might search all of the queues to their full depth to determine whether a packet was dropped or misrouted. Or you could simply halt the simulation and debug it interactively from there.

Comment: Dave, thank you. But when a packet appears on the input port, which of the 16 queues will you push it into? Plus when the packet comes on the output ports, we have no clue whether its a A port packet, or a B port packet or a C port packet or a D port packet.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't tell where the packet is going to end up from its contents? How does the DUT do it? WRT the output packets, that's why I said you need to examine four of the queues.

Comment: Consider the DUT as a huge blackbox and its an IP (no visibility inside). In that case, any idea on how do I keep track of the packets for checking?

Comment: No. If you can't predict the behavior of the DUT, there's no way to verify whether it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can have  a multidimensional associative array of queue with first index being the output port, second index being the input port for a referral data structure. A particular packet is queued depending on its input & output ports.
when transactions are observed on output ports, you can pop the expected packet from the referral data structure & compare.

This way you will only verify the order of packets for each input port.